# 8 bit color to UIColor

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicolor

I get some 8 bit color code from XML file and need to represent some text with this color. 
For example: red color is: 255 ( 0XE0), black color is: 0 (0X00); 
How can I init the UIColor with this 8 bit code? 
The really expensive way is to split the code in 3 red bits, 3 green bits and 2 blue bits and then divide and multiple and so one and so far. Maybe someone know the easy way to do this?

Comment: How is red 255? What would be green or blue in your example? Also using a bitmask isn't really expensive.

Comment: If your color is RGB coded with 3:3:2 bits, then 0xE0 should be red, 0xC1 green and 0x03 is blue - 0xFF is not red, but white.

Comment: *I do not see anything wrong with this question which would force me to down vote the question!*

Comment: using bitwise operators is not expensive way at all. they are usually the fastest operators.

Comment: bitwise operations are among the fastest things a processor can do. if you're concerned about the diving part, it's very likely the compiler will optimize that to be multiplications (i.e. instead of dividing by 7 or 3 depending on the number of bits of the field, multiply by a precalculated 1/7 or 1/3, which is faster). You can do that manually if in doubt

Comment: @Constantin : Yeah, you are right. I watched at the wrong place in XML.
Red is 0XE0. I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your color is RGB coded with `3:3:2` bits, then `0xE0` should be red, `0xC1` green and `0x03` is blue - `0xFF` is not red, but white. I'm assuming your example with `0xFF` being red was probably wrong. To convert your 8-bit coded color into an `UIColor` you just have to apply an bitmask for the color component and normalize the values.

Notice that the 3 bit values have the range `0-7`, and the 2 bit value has only a range from `0-3`.

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((bitValue & 0xE0) >> 5) / 7.0f) green:((bitValue & 0xC1) >> 2) / 7.0f) blue:((bitValue & 0x03) / 3.0f) alpha:1.0f];
```

[Reference to UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)